# what is ILO usability

Tags: ilo

If you guys can tell me about ILO in HP and its usage

Comment: For your info, this is my downvote on this question because you have demonstrated no effort in researching this yourself. I'm not usually a "look on Google" kind of guy, but this time I feel wholly justified. If you have a *specific* question about how iLO works or whether it does a specific task, please update your question and I'll consider removing my downvote. Also, [see this SO blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) about questions which are too simple.

Comment: You might start by checking the documentation on the CD that came with the server. If you don't have the CD check the HP web site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iLO makes it possible to perform activities on an HP server from a remote location. The iLO card has a separate network connection (and its own IP address) to which one can connect via HTTPS. Possible options are:

> reset the server (in case the server
>   doesn't respond anymore via the normal
>   network card)
>
> power-up the server (possible to do
>   this from a remote location, even if
>   the server is shut down)
>
> remote console (in some cases however
>   an 'Advanced license' maybe required
>   for some of the utilities to work)
>
> mount remote physical CD/DVD drive or
>   image.
>
> access the server's IML (Integrated
>   Management Log)
>
> can be manipulated remotely through
>   xml-based Remote Insight Board Command
>   Language (RIBCL)
>
> Full CLI support through RS-232 port
>   (shared with system).
>
> iLO provides some other utilities like
>   virtual media (CD, floppy), virtual
>   power and a remote console. iLO is
>   always embedded on the System Board.

From 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Integrated_Lights-Out

Answer (score 6):

HP iLO is the [integrated lights out management](http://h18013.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/remotemgmt.html?jumpid=servers/lights-out) - a remote control system for a server.

Comment: what it can be used for exactly ?

Comment: @Eddy - please don't be lazy. Iain included a link that describes what it does. If you've read that link and are still stuck then perhaps you could explain what parts you don't understand.

Answer (score 6):

The ILO is an HP ProLiant feature and is a form of [out-of-band management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management) for a server system.

Please see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management